# Duplicate Management is failing for data-loader loading two identical new records

Tags: duplicate-management

I have created a matching rule based on a group of three fields;

```
(Campsite: f1EXACTMatchBlank = TRUE) AND 
(Campsite: f2EXACTMatchBlank = TRUE) AND 
(Campsite: f3EXACTMatchBlank = TRUE)
```

Here F1,F2 and  F3 are the three fields on object Campsite.

I have used the same and created a Duplicate Rule with blocking edit and create if duplicate is already present.

The duplicate rule works fine in all case whether created/update through UI or dataloader; except when I insert a pair of identical new records using data loader.

i.e. **two records with same value for F1,F2,F3 but similar record is not present in system yet.**

**In this case it is inserting both the records.**

Is it the correct behavior of duplicate management? Is there any document referring to this behavior?

If it is the correct behavior then can anyone tell me how should I handle this?

**Note:** I have one more duplicate rule on the same object to validate duplicate names as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like documented behaviour, indeed:

> If you’re saving multiple records at the same time and your duplicate rules are set to Block or Alert, records within the same save aren’t compared to each other; they are only compared with records already in Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_management_considerations.htm&language=en_US

I guess the duplicate management as it currently is is more oriented towards GUI-based actions and feedback.
If you really need to be sure that no duplicates exist on database level, you should better revert to an alternative method:

1. create a new textfield 'UniqueId' and create a workflow rule that updates that field with a concatenation of the fields that should be unique (in your case e.g. `F1 & "-" & F2 & "-" & F3`)
   or
2. create an apex trigger (after insert/update) that queries the complete table and checks for any duplicates

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I will try these approaches and let you know.

Comment: However I am thinking of creating duplicate rule and keeping a before insert-update trigger to check duplicate in current chunk of records. How does this approach sound? And the confusing point is I have two such rules on the same object.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy - I'd really only have either the before insert trigger or the duplicate rule as it would be confusing if anyone needs to remove this check and has it coming in 2 places. Its true that duplicate management is focused on GUI actions not the API updates of data which is a limitation, but I suspect is necessary for performance reasons.

Comment: @DaveHumm yes. Even I feel it will become very confusing for someone maintaining this application at a later point of time. But why salesforce is not providing that out of the box :( Now I am thinking of creating only duplicate rules as client is not using data loader for this table, and making client aware of not using data loader for this object.

Comment: Hey @Guy, Is there a way that I could customize the error message for your first approach?

Comment: @Saumyae I'm afraid not. That's the drawback of this approach. The positive side is that no code is required.. I wonder what the behaviour is if you combine approach #1 with the dupe rule. You might get the dupe notification first, which will give you the user experience you want?